# Compute the heading variations

Tags: matlab, conceptual

I have a GPS track log, I have registered the heading of navigation (i.e. for every logged point I have trace the heading). As far as I observed, this heading vary between 0 and 360.
So, in log we can find:

> 1. 0.002
> 2. 0.1
> 3. 359.2
> 4. 0.01

Consider now point 3 and 4. Obviously, the car hasn't perform a 360 rotation. It just moves few degree (0.81) on another heading trajectory. So the margin is not abs(359.2-0.01) or abs(0.01-359.2). I clearly need a more sophisticated way to compute the changing.
I think that I need to compute abs(359.2-0.01)=359.19 and next 360-359.19=0.81. Can I consider this as my standard modus operandi to compute direction change?
I'm on matlab, so maybe there's a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
mod(a-b+180, 360) - 180
```

Example:

```
>> f = @(a,b) mod(a-b+180, 360) - 180;
>> f(359.2, 0.01)
ans = -0.81000
>> f(0.01, 359.2)
ans =  0.81000
>> f(358.2, 359.2)
ans = -1
>> f(0.01, 1.01)
ans = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Oli Chalesworth does what you want. There is also the matlab function [unwrap](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/unwrap.html) that adds or subtracts 2π to minimize the relative angle between two points. The downside is that it expects the angle to be in radians.

```
original_angles=[.002 .1 359.2 .001];
smooth_angles=180/pi*unwrap(original_angles*pi/180)
```

gives
    smooth_angles =

```
    0.0020    0.1000   -0.8000    0.0010
```